# Problema ao conectar em banco de dados no Google Cloud e Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Estou usando o Google Cloud Platform, mas estou com dificuldade para me conectar ao banco de dados MySQL da própria plataforma com o AppEngine.

Segue o meu pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? />
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.daniel</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeuTempoApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SeuTempoApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.0.0.RC1</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Arquivo application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=(nome da instancia sql da google)
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=(nome do banco)
spring.datasource.username=(usuario)
spring.datasource.password=(senha)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Quando eu executo o comando appengine:run os teste passando sem erro porem ao iniciar a aplicação o sistema o sistema exibe a seguinte exceção:

```
    [INFO] GCLOUD: Jul 18, 2018 12:21:13 AM com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory connect
    [INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [seutempoapi:us-central1:basedemo].
    [INFO] GCLOUD: Jul 18, 2018 12:21:13 AM com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory connect
    [INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Using GAE Unix Sockets
    [INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-07-18 00:21:15.156 ERROR 393 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
    [INFO] GCLOUD:
    [INFO] GCLOUD: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    [INFO] GCLOUD:
    [INFO] GCLOUD: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:342) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3472430.getConnection(<generated>) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43257a9c.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43257a9c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a51a185.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43257a9c.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389) ~[jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:9.3.18.v20170406]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:347) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:282) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:395) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:247) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:238) ~[na:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.doConnect(UnixSocketChannel.java:127) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.18.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.connect(UnixSocketChannel.java:136) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.18.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.open(UnixSocketChannel.java:68) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.18.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.8.jar:na]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 130 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Como está sua configuração de aceso ao banco? De uma olhada na ajuda e procure prover um [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A conexão com o banco de dados esta ok, ao executar o comando mvn spring-boot:run a aplicação roda normal, porém quando eu executo o comando appengine:run para rodar pelo google cloud da erro

Comment: Tive um problema semelhante, com a mesma mensagem de erro, porém no meu caso eu estava utilizando o postgres e a dependência do socket. No meu caso, a versão 1.0.14 não funcionou. Depois de 3 dias pesquisando muito na internet, resolvi mudar a versão do socket, fiz um downgrade para versão 1.0.12 e magicamente funcionou. <dependency> <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId> <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId> <version>1.0.12</version> </dependency>